# Having issue with tr_MStran_droptable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm being prohibited from dropping any table from a db because of this trigger. I can't figure out why it is applying. The table(s) in question are not part of cdc or replication (neither has EVER been enabled on this instance, much less this db)

Nor are the tables in question showing up in...

OBJECT_ID('dbo.sysarticles') IS NULL OR OBJECT_ID('dbo.syspublications') IS NULL OR OBJECT_ID('dbo.sysextendedarticlesview')

any of those tables (from the trigger)

Google is no help, has anyone ran in to this before?

edit - entire trigger text

```
/****** Object:  DdlTrigger [tr_MStran_droptable]    Script Date: 12/16/2016 12:32:18 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [tr_MStran_droptable] ON DATABASE FOR DROP_TABLE AS 

                            SET ANSI_NULLS ON
                            SET ANSI_PADDING ON
                            SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
                            SET ARITHABORT ON
                            SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
                            SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
                            SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

                            DECLARE @EventData XML
                            SET @EventData=EVENTDATA()

                            IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.sysarticles') IS NULL OR OBJECT_ID('dbo.syspublications') IS NULL OR OBJECT_ID('dbo.sysextendedarticlesview') IS NULL OR EXISTS(
                               SELECT 1
                                 FROM @EventData.nodes('/EVENT_INSTANCE') AS R(event_instance)
                                WHERE LOWER(event_instance.value('SchemaName[1]', 'sysname')) IN (N'sys', N'cdc')
                                   OR LOWER(event_instance.value('ObjectName[1]', 'sysname')) IN (N'sysextendedarticlesview', N'sysarticles', N'syspublications')
                                   OR event_instance.value('ObjectName[1]', 'sysname') LIKE N'#%'
                            ) RETURN

                            EXEC sys.sp_MStran_ddlrepl @EventData, 5
    GO

    ENABLE TRIGGER [tr_MStran_droptable] ON DATABASE
    GO
```

Comment: Can you post the entire trigger?

Comment: Added in original question (tried to do it in comments, too much text)

Comment: Try running `sp_removedbreplication 'DB_NAME'` that will remove replication.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47234/8783

Comment: running removereplication worked, however it doesn't explain the deeper mystery to me. Why would this affect tables that have never been replicated, on a db where nothing was being replicated from or to?

Comment: Also, nothing shows up in the tables the trigger is checking. unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after upgrading to SQL Server 2016, and removing all replication was not an option.

For me, the solution was adding SP1 to my SQL Server 2016 instances.

The error had come when the trigger called sp_MStran_ddlrepl (in its last step, above). That stored procedure wasn't expecting "5" as the second parameter on a couple of upgraded servers. Running SP1 altered that stored procedure making "5" an acceptable parameter.